# How to tell when back button is pressed in a UINavigationControllerStack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to check when the back button is pressed in a UINavigationController stack? I've tried adding a action and target to self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem to no avail.

Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: When you change the backBarButtonItem, make sure you are changing it on the controller that you are going back /to/, not the one that was just pushed. Also, you can only set a custom title or a custom view. If you set a custom image, it has no effect. Finally, you can use Noah's suggestion below, but make yourself the delegate of the navigation controller itself, and respond to the didPopViewController: family of methods.

Comment: UINavigationControllerDelegate doesn't have will/didPopViewController methods, only will/didShowViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my way:

Write in your ViewController:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBt = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNameOfBackButton"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backBt_touch:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBt;
```

And action method:

```
- (void)backBt_touch:(id)sender {
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

You have to take a photo of back button you want.

Animation of hiding back button when viewController is popped is not the same animation of iOS!

P/s: [image]
I've get it from simulator. Hope it useful! :)

Answer (score -1):

One way to get at this would be to override `viewWillDisappear` in the UIViewController that is visible when the back button is pressed:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
        // handle back button press
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't directly intercept the press on the back button itself, but it gives you a chance to perform logic at that time.

Comment: This's a idea but... `viewWillDisappear` will be called in too many case. This is not perfect way!

Comment: I could be missing something, but I think checking for `self.isMovingFromParentViewController` solves that problem.

Comment: @mon4goos the self.isMovingFromParentViewController doesn't work

Comment: Well it does work, and it is better than using `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` which shows no back arrow. This answer got demoted for no reason.